# What's the current leak path of the electrostatic discharge during an EMC test?

Tags: emc, discharge, electrostatic

When we develop a new product we need to pass the EMC test.  I really wonder what the current path during a  electrostatic discharge test is.

Here is the test situation：

1. If the EUT (equipment under test) is a metal shell, is there a discharge path? If yes, what's the path going to? The ground?
2. If the EUT is not a metal shield (for example a plastic shell,) does a path exist? What's the discharge path?

---

Let's assume the EUT is a battery powered plastic shell device which has a PCB inside. When we do the electrostatic discharge test at a voltage of +-6.6kV, the discharge current has an influence on the device such that it causes it to work abnormal. So what's the discharge current path?

[image]
[image]

---

[updated]
I added a new picture to assume the discharge current loop, that is my confusion.

Can I always find the discharging current loop in my test?

Q1 is easy to consider as the discharging current flows through the metal shell, but in the situation of Q2 I cannot find a current path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If there are power cords, then the ESD discharge may use the 117VAC power lines.

If the DUT is floating atop insulation, then the Displacement Current is the path.

Comment: Excuse me，what do you mean by "the Displacement Current is the path"

Comment: @lukeluck I think the sentence is pretty clear. The path for the current is *displacement current*; you won't get far on this topic without basic understanding of solid state electronics and Maxwell...

Comment: displacement current is a definition？can you draw me a picture like figure3？

Comment: Use wikipedia. One example of displacement current is how current flows through a capacitor while no electrons jump from one plate to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The EUT will have a reactive path that must withstand the dielectric breakdown of the applied discharge electric field.  It may also have a 0V conductive shield or an EMI spray ground that shields the impulse E field from inerference.

Damage or false operation may occur from ground shift, inductive signal induction, conducted signal or capacitive or inductive coupling to signals.

> This way you do not have to feel the current spike.

Even portable testers have a proper ground connection, so there is an inductive current loop, but the good testers are low inductance which can raise the spectrum of the discharge noise.

[image]

Comment: 真的吗 ?  This tester is the best Swiss brand

Comment: As we know，there must be a loop so that the current can flow,in my Q1 I think the current loop is that the charge flow to ground throw metal shell,is this thought correct? And in my Q2,obviously there there does not exist such a loop,if there is no loop then how the current flow?（but in reality I really see the discharge spark during my battery powered EMC test）.I can't understand how the charge transfer?